# Find Replace in Notepad++ - EOL character followed by lower case character

Tags: notepad++

Someone was helpful and supplied me with the following to find a lowercase character followed by an EOL;
`([a-z])\R` - this worked perfectly - so I thought maybe using the opposite would give me an EOL followed by a lowercase character like this;
`\R([a-z])` - but this does not seem to work, in fact it seems to find lines starting with uppercase letters. I may well be doing something wrong or need enlightening.

Example - Before

```
"Thanks very much for sending the pictures" CRLF
he saidCRLF
```

After

```
"Thanks very much for sending the pictures" he saidCRLF
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide some example text (before and after the changes required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not seem to work. In fact, it seems to find lines starting with uppercase letters.

If you want to `Match case`, you'll need to have that option checked:

[image: Notepad++ - Match Case - Screenshot]

`Match case` should respect `\R([a-z])` (lower case) and `\R([A-Z])` (uppercase). If `Match case` isn't checked, `\R([a-z])` will match both lower and uppercase letters. You'll also likely want to have `Wrap around` checked as well, assuming you want your regular expression search to be "restarted" at the beginning of the document after reaching the final match.

As an obvious caveat, you will need to have some lines that start with a lower case letter for `\R([a-z])` to work at all.